# Morphing multiple executables into a single application

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, qt4, openmp

I have three legacy applications that share a lot of source code and data. Multiple instances of each of these applications be executed by a user at any time, e.g. a dozen mixed application executions can be active at a time. These applications currently communicate through shared memory and messaging techniques so that they can maintain common cursor positioning, etc. The applications are written primarily in C++, use Qt and run in total to about 5 million lines of code. Only some of the existing code is threadsafe.

I want to consolidate these three executables into a single executable and use multi-threading functionality to allow multiple instance of each of the three functionality branches to execute at the same time. It has been suggested that I look into some of the features provided by Boost, e.g. shared pointers, and use OpenMP to orchestrate overall execution of the multiple threads.

Any comments on how to proceed will be appreciated, particularly references on the best way to tackle this kind of a refactoring problem.

Comment: why not use the existing threading classes that Qt offers if your code is Qt based?

Comment: Why do you want to make the changes? Performance? Architecture?

There is probably an easier way to improve either one of those than multi-threading.

Comment: What's wrong with the current design?

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion to you would be design the desired solution first (firstly assuming that the requirements are the same) and then build a phased migration path from the existing code base basing it on the requirements that third party functionality may introduce.

Refactoring should be one small step at a time - but knowing where you are going.

The [Working Effectively with Legacy Code (Robert C. Martin Series)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052)  will be a good read I'd suggest.

Trust me (I've got the t shirts) don't attempt to refactor unless you know how to prove functionality - automated verification tests will be your saviour.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think anyone will be able to give you an informed answer. There are too many things to take into considerations. Only after careful analysis of the processes involved and the code behind would anyone (you included) be able to provide you with a project path.

That said, there are however a few things you should take into consideration.

1. Your applications and the way they seem to communicate with each other seems to me an already sound solution. This is so, especially because you have 5 million lines of code to tackle with, if you choose to get into refactoring your current system. This is a strong deterrent. If there is a need to provide threading support in order to optimize current application messaging, I'd perhaps suggest you consider the possibility of introducing MT into the shared memory and messaging routines, instead of merging applications.
2. The act of merging your applications could be seen at first glance as the "simple" act of gluing your current code and removing the current routines responsible for memory sharing and messaging, replacing them with normal function calls to the glued objects. My gut tells me it will not be that simple. You have to consider that almost certainly your current backbone code was designed for the current messaging solution. Your current abstractions were thought of with this in mind. You will almost certainly find that you will also need to make significant changes to existing backbone code. And again here you will find that wall of 5 million lines a huge problem. Because changes will quickly propagate across your entire system  and leave you with 5 million lines of code to handle and god knows how many new bugs.
3. I'd suggest 1 above. But it may be that you do need for some reason to consolidate your applications. That being so, I'd still suggest something else before you try 2. Create an *interface application* responsible for firing up, displaying and maintaining the current 3 applications. Your users will know no better if you do this right. You'll still be able to apply 1 to your current system and join your applications under a common interface, despite them being in fact separate entities.

Answer (score 0):

"...about 5 million lines of code..." Hmm... It is hard to say for sure without knowing your system, but since it is a "legacy" system, you can probably gain a lot by removing code duplication. Check out [Simian](http://www.redhillconsulting.com.au/products/simian/) and [CPD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/cpd.html).

5 million lines is *a lot* ot code. Of course, you may need it, but my guess is that you don't.

You definitely need a good reason to change a change a code-base like that to be multi-threaded, especially in C++. Doing it without cleaning it up completely first is a recipe for disaster.